# PyQt clipboard doesn't copy to system clipboard

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, clipboard

The following snippet of code doesn't seem to affect the system clipboard at all:

```
clipboard = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
clipboard.setText(text)
```

According to the Qt documentation, this is how you copy text to clipboard,

Why isn't it working?

Googling turned [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg17328.html) up.

It suggests adding this after the above code:

```
event = QtCore.QEvent(QtCore.QEvent.Clipboard)
app.sendEvent(clipboard, event)
```

But this one behaves odd: it only copies the text to the clipboard after the program exits. Plus, some people in that link reported that this doesn't work with linux.

#### UPDATE:

Nevermind, I was doing something wrong else where, instead of binding the copy slot to the copy button, I connected it to the "quit" button.

Answer (score 16):

You may need to specify the [mode](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qclipboard.html#Mode-enum).

This code worked for me on windows:

```
    cb = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
    cb.clear(mode=cb.Clipboard )
    cb.setText("Clipboard Text", mode=cb.Clipboard)
```

Comment: Works perfectly... However, for PyQt5 (and PyQt6) you get the clipboard via `QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard()`

Answer (score 5):

I know you are not using Windows, but maybe this will give you some ideas... I used this in a PyQt program to copy URLs to the clipboard:

```
import win32clipboard

s = 'copy this to the clipboard'
try:
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(s)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
except:
    print 'Could not copy clipboard data.'
```

Comment: I'm on windows actually (mainly, though I do have a linuxmint installation)

Comment: win32clipboard seems like a great candidate for some updates, specifically a context manager `with win32clipboard.open() as my_clipboard:` to do the open, empty, and close parts.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my English. I use linux. I wrote only this command

QApplication.clipboard().setText("This is text 2 clipboard")

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use code style to highlight your code. https://www.udrop.com/947h/Capture.PNG   Also, it seems like original question poster already used what you suggested and later on, add a new part to say that he already solved it and problem was somewhere else. So the question has already been solved solved

Answer (score 0):

You might try [gtk.Clipboard](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkclipboard.html) from [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/about.html).  I believe it is multi-platform.

This might be part of the reason you're having trouble with PyQt's [QClipboard](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qapplication.html#clipboard) object:

> **QClipboard QApplication.clipboard ()**
>
> Returns a pointer to the application
>   global clipboard.
>
> Note: The QApplication object should
>   already be constructed before
>   accessing the clipboard.

<strike>It's pointing to the *application* clipboard, not the system clipboard. You'll probably have to use something other than the QClipboard object to achieve your end.</strike>

**Edit:**

The above conclusion from the cited documentation is incorrect.  According to the actual [PyQt documentation of the QClipboard](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qclipboard.html) object:

> The QClipboard class provides access to the window system clipboard.

Comment: @Chris Morgan, thanks for pointing that out! I've gone back and updated the answer.